# Making VF page list items (custom object & controller), go to detail page, add 'return' button?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am creating a page to be placed on my customer community site that will show contractual employees their past/present/future events on a list. My goal is to be able to click those list items and open an `<apex:detail>` page (what would be awesome would be to toggle expansion of a pane underneath the item on the list, but if that is terribly involved it will wait for another day). These users should not have the ability to *edit* these records, just to see a few pieces of information on the list which is either expandable to show more detail or linked to a following vf `<apex:detail>` page.

Without much of a background in SF and practically no background in coding, I have come up with this so far. The list on the vf page populates properly, but I can't seem to find a document detailing how I might make something here clickable.

This is a preferable alternative to my other option, which is to embed a visual workflow, which I know how to do; I'd simply like the configurable style that visualforce gives me.

My vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="displayEvents" >
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <apex:pageBlock>
            <h1>
                <font size="12">Viewing your events</font>
            </h1>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mps}" var="mp">
            <apex:column value="{!mp.confirmed_admin_date__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!mp.project_tracking__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!mp.exam_start_time__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!mp.check_in__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!mp.check_out__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!mp.event_cancelled__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

My controller:

```
public class displayEvents {

    public string var_CurrentUserEmail = UserInfo.getUserEmail();

    public Market_Project__c mp;

    public ApexPages.StandardSetcontroller setCon{
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT confirmed_admin_date__c, exam_start_time__c, project_tracking__c,
                    check_in__c, check_out__c, event_cancelled__c
                    FROM Market_Project__c
                    WHERE confirmed_supervisor_email__c = : var_CurrentUserEmail]));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }
    public List<Market_Project__c> getMPs() {
        return (List<Market_Project__c>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$Action` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm) may be of use to you here. Of the [valid values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm), the following are supported on `Custom Objects`:

- Clone
- Delete
- Edit
- List
- New
- View

Also of note is how `URLFOR` works ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)). Its signature is:

```
{!URLFOR(target, id, [inputs], [no override])}
```

So you can pass page parameters through it as well in the third parameter. This will be necessary if you want to link to a page.

---

**Implementation Options**

A quick and dirty implementation is to just link one of the fields:

```
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Market_Project__c.fields. project_tracking__c.Label}">
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Market_Project__c.Edit, mp.Id)}">
        {!mp.project_tracking__c}
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

If you want to link to a `Visualforce Page` instead:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Page.MyPage, null, [Id=mp.Id])}">
    Link Text
</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: I'm not looking to allow the viewers of the page to edit any of the information- they will use a separate app for recording check in/out times. The perfect implementation will show a few key pieces of information (the columns on the list currently) and clicking one of the list items will expand or redirect to a page with more information about the event.

Comment: @jatuttle0 What exactly do you mean by "clickable" then?

Comment: How might I adapt {!URLFOR()} to link to another custom visualforce page instead of the standard detail page layout?

Comment: @jatuttle0 Added detail.

Comment: @AdrianLarson May I suggest adding detail on how to pass parameters, such as object id, to a VF page via URLFOR?

Comment: @DougB will do.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an [`<apex:outputLink />`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) to provide a clickable link which can open a new tab in combination with [`URLFOR`](https://eltoro.secure.force.com/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000NPRjBIAX) to send the user to the Detail page of the event.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Marketing_Project__c.View, mp.Id)}">{!mp.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

As for expanding a pane underneath, that's a bit more effort and given you have no coding background you might want to put off for now.